# Regular sequence in degree 1

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

$R$ is a graded algebra generated by $R_1$(the degree 1 piece) over $R_0=k$ where $k$ is a infinite field and R has no negative degree. Given irrelevant ideal has depth d, then is it possible to find a regular sequence of length d with elements in $R_1$?

I am trying to prove this by assuming we do not have length d regular sequence in degree 1, and show this is impossible. But I get no where. Even when assume the maximal length of regular sequence consisting of elements of degree 1 is just 1, say $x$ is a nonzero divisor, how can I tell $(x^2+x^4,x^2+x^5)$ is not a regular sequence?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See Bruns and Herzog, 1.5.12.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much! I will look it up!

Comment: @user26857 I have read 1.5.12, and I guess for regular sequence I can let the primes be the associated primes, therefore I can get nonzero divisors right? But after I get $(x_1,...,x_d)$, I do know $x_d$ is not a zero divisor in $R/R(x_1,...,x_{d-1}$, but how can I make sure that $R(x_1,...,x_d)$ is not equal to $R$? Thanks!

Comment: @user26857 Oh, sorry, since depth is less than cxdimension, principal ideal theorem implies it is impossible. Never mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See Bruns and Herzog, Proposition 1.5.12.